# Phrase on expressing opinion on other's draft

Tags: expressions

I am working on a group project and need to comment on others' entries/drafts/contributions. How could I express "you draft is good and we will go with it?" in a more formal way? Thanks so much!!

Comment: @BenjaminHarman Sorry if this post does not fit into the forum, however as I assume this is a forum for language learners, which means they do not perfectly master that language. Besides, people work together for many different reasons, one of them is to utilize their professional expertise, not their foreign language skills.

Comment: There's actually a different SE for [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm not sure that there's anything essentially informal about the existing statement. The wording could be improved, but it's not informal because of that. Anything else suggested would be subjective. You could use something like this: *We have decided your proposal is best, and will be proceeding with it.* But all I've done is make the wording more stuffy, not necessarily more formal. And that's only one of many different ways of phrasing it.

Comment: There’s a workplace.se. You could try there. Should you consider the others?